# Values between a date Google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, max, min

I have a more than 10k rows with date time values and would like to filter them by date.

Like the example below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A:A; INT(A:A)=C2)
```

min:

```
=MIN(FILTER(A:A; INT(A:A)=C2))
```

max:

```
=MAX(FILTER(A:A; INT(A:A)=C2))
```

Comment: That's awesome! Do you mind helping my with getting the lowest value and the highest? Small and min are not working

Comment: @mau answer updated. see if that helps